# Why is Google Maps overridding my div tag

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I created a div tag called "map-canvas" where google maps is residing. In my style sheet I have set the position to fixed, but when I open the browser and inspect I see google maps has overriden my style with its own and changed position fixed to position: relative. Why? How can I override google from doing this? I tried putting style attributes right in the tag but google still overrode these values.

before

```
#map-canvas {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 40%;
height: 900px;
background-color: pink;
/* border: 3px solid black; */
}
```

after

```
element.style {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps: Relative to Fixed Positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219709/google-maps-relative-to-fixed-positioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `new google.maps.Map(element)` Google will do whatever it wants to that `element`.  Instead attach the google maps to an element within your styled element:

css:

```
#map-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 40%;
height: 900px;
background-color: pink;
/* border: 3px solid black; */
}
```

html:

```
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map-canvas">
  </div>
</div>
```